# Is there any way to configure a Delta<TEntity> to change the UpdatableProperties property in OData?

Tags: odata

I am using OData implementation to add a service to do CRUD operations, the classes I am using have some fields that should not be updated, so I am calling a function that uses a List to filter the properties:

```
private List<string> ReservedPropertiesName = new List<string>() { "ObjectId", "IsDeleted", "DeleterUserId", "DeletionTime", "LastModificationTime", "LastModifierUserId", "CreationTime", "CreatorUserId", "CreatorUser", "TenantId" };


public TEntity FilterUpdatableProperties(TEntity entity)
        {
            Delta<TEntity> delta = new Delta<TEntity>(entity.GetType());
            ReservedPropertiesName.ForEach(p => delta.UpdatableProperties.Remove(p));
            SetDeltaEntityValues(ref delta, entity);

            return delta.GetInstance();
        }

        public void SetDeltaEntityValues(ref Delta<TEntity> delta,TEntity entity)
        {            
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                delta.TrySetPropertyValue(propertyInfo.Name, entity.GetValueByName(propertyInfo.Name));
            }
        }
```

I want to configure the Delta to remove some of the updatable properties before the Patch method is called.